# How can i convert Func<T,object> to PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, func

I need property name to be extracted form Func please help me if its possible. Thanks.

```
public void Converter<T>(Func<T,Ojbect> F)
{

}
public class Tester
{
 void main()
  {
   String Name = Converter<User>(m=>m.Id);
  //Name should be equal to "Id"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var memberExpress = property.Body as MemberExpression;    
    return memberExpress.Member.Name;
}
```

Which you can then call using:

```
var user = new User();
string name = GetPropertyName(() => user.Name);
```

Or even:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> property)
{
    var memberExpress = property.Body as MemberExpression;    
    return memberExpress.Member.Name;
}
```

Which you can call using:

```
string name = GetPropertyName<User, string>(u => u.Id);
```

Comment: The variable `user` is not needed in the last example.